# Store based email template not working with magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, email, email-templates

I am having magento 1.9.2 portal with english & arabic language stores. When i had register or order a product i get transactional emails in english itsef.

Then i had do like this "system - transactional emails" there i had created new template for arabic and saved for register confirmation mail in store based.

But, when i had register with english store also receiving the arabic store email.

I want to fix this one

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to **System -> Configuration -> Sales email** and then switch your **Current Configuration Scope** to English store.

After that uncheck use Website checkbox after **New Order Confirmation Template** in Order section, set your English template an save.

Repeat that step for the **New Order Confirmation Template for Guest**.

Comment: Yes done, but not working

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign these special mail templates under

```
System -> Configuration -> Customer

System -> Configuration -> Sales Emails.
```

Email templates should be set as per store view.

Check email template in store configuration.

You can select you store, left top of page : **Current Configuration Scope:**

Comment: Yes, i had set that one. But no use not working

Comment: Different email template for different store ?

Comment: Yes, i am having different email address in different stores, but receiving the same arabic mail for english also

Comment: Email template should be created for different store, change template content as per you want to. correct template assign in store configuration in admin.

Comment: this is the way i had configured the stores http://awesomescreenshot.com/0db65z6p02

Comment: You checked wrong configuration, tell me which email you are test, sales or register customer ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47307/discussion-between-s-h-patel-and-xproecommerce).

Comment: No use, i had set the language package also. Still not working

Comment: When you load template from arabic language it will show in arabic.

Comment: @S H Patel  
I had load the template from arabic language only. But, still it's not working any more.

Comment: When you load template from arabic language, it content should be load in arabic language.

Comment: I am unable to find the language pack for arabic. I had done like this.
1. Create a language folder with file manager under "public_html/app/locale/ar_SA"

Loaded email templates from public_html/app/locale/ar_SA/template/email